# How to add up three bytes in Scala?

Tags: scala, binary, byte

I have tried many ways but dont still know how to do this:

```
def to24Bits(p: Int, q: Int, r: Int): Int =  { 
   (p<<8|q<<16|r<<24)
}


to24Bits(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00) => 0xFF0000

to24Bits(0x00, 0xFF, 0x00) => 0x0000FF

to24Bits(0x00, 0xFF, 0x00) => 0x0000FF

to24Bits(0x11, 0x22, 0x33) => 0x112233

to24Bits(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF) => 0xFFFFFF
```

I edited this:

```
to24Bits(0xffffff11, 0xffffff88, 0xffffff00) => 0x118800
```

Comment: I'm not following. Are you looking for the String representation of the byte in hex?

Comment: Your third and fourth examples are inconsistent. Otherwise, I'd suggest to try it with `(p << 16) | (q << 8) | r`, and close it as trivial typo...

Comment: Didn't work out.

Comment: What *"didn't work out"*? That's not the proper way to report errors if you want someone else to be able to understand what went wrong.

Comment: Sorry im new here. To24Bits(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF)) went wrong.

Comment: Gives `ffffff`, as expected. Unclear what the problem with the `0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF` is supposed to be, see answer.

Comment: Expected:<1148928> but was <-256>. Aa sorry its bug is to24Bits(0xffffff11, 0xffffff88, 0xffffff00) => 0x118800.

Comment: The code below gives you the `0xFFFFFF`, what's the problem? And where does the strange `1148928` come from? `0xFFFFFF` is 16777215 (these are exactly the "16 million colors", as advertised on monitors in the old days).

Comment: I edited first post.

Comment: I edited the answer.

Comment: Yes thank you man!

Comment: This is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If (for whatever reason) you want to feed negative integers to it, then you have to cut off all bits above the first byte with `& 0xFF`:

```
def to24Bits(p: Int, q: Int, r: Int): Int = {
  ((p & 0xFF) << 16) | ((q & 0xFF) << 8) | (r & 0xFF)
}
```

Your examples:

```
for ((p, q, r) <- List(
  (0xFF, 0x00, 0x00),
  (0x00, 0xFF, 0x00),
  (0x00, 0x00, 0xFF),
  (0x11, 0x22, 0x33),
  (0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF),
  (0xffffff11, 0xffffff88, 0xffffff00)
)) {
  printf("0x%06X\n", to24Bits(p, q, r))
}
```

Output:

```
0xFF0000
0x00FF00
0x0000FF
0x112233
0xFFFFFF
0x118800
```